# print a variable generated from another .php file

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to display the value of $codeOut from a php file called get_rebate.php.

Currently I am using:

```
<?php include ("get_rebate.php"); echo substr($codeOut,7); ?>
```

to try and get the output of $codeOut from get_rebate.php to appear in the page but instead it returns the error message that get_rebate.php generates when it can't verify the value.

I'm probably not calling the result of get_rebate.php ($codeOut) properly but looking for guidance with this problem.

get_rebate.php:

```
<?
$code=$_GET['code'];
$rnum=50000-$_GET['rnum'];

if ($code=="2210" || $code==$rnum) {
    makeVerifier($code);
} else { echo "The Rebate Code you have entered (" . $code . ") does not apply to this product.\nPlease consult with your Fitness Expert and request if a Rebate Code\nis available for this product.";
}
function makeVerifier($codeIn) {
    $len=strlen($codeIn);
    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
        $codeOut.=ord(substr($codeIn,$i));
        if (strlen($codeOut)>7) {break;}
    }
    echo "Congratulations! Your Manufacturers Rebate Verification Code is M" . substr($codeOut,0,7);
}
?>
```

The output on the page is: The Rebate Code you have entered () does not apply to this product. Please consult with your Fitness Expert and request if a Rebate Code is available for this product

Comment: You need to show the contents of get_rebate.php or explain what it does

Comment: can you post the contents of get_rebate.php.  If that is returning an error message then execution is probably halting and never reaching you echo.

Comment: whoops, updated with get_rebate.php. you'll see that the message i'm getting back is what the script echos when it can't verify the code

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `$code` is not 2210 or `$rnum` so you get the error message. Even if the code would be correct, it wouldn't work: `$codeOut`'s scope is limited to the `makeVerifier()` function. You need to call it with `$codeOut = makeVerifier( $code )` and at the end of the function add `return $codeOut`.

Comment: excellent the $codeOut = makeVerifier('$code') is exactly what I was looking for. the current function returns the message about the rebate code not being correct and then returns the correct $codeOut value (i think because of the way get_rebate.php is set up).